# Differences in MFCC values

Tags: signal-processing, mfcc

I wrote my own code to extract MFCC, the algorithm is as follows:

1. data from file.wav
2. pre-emphasis according to the expression
   x'[n] = x[n] - 0,97 * x[n-1]
3. framing signal, frame length 480, overlap 240
4. STFT with hamming window 480 long and 512-point FFT, that is 480 values and 32 zeros.
   w[n] = 0,54 - 0,46 * cos(2*pi*n/(N-1))'
5. creating a filter bank using the **formula** [image: formula]
6. calculate the energy E[k] = |X[k]|^2
   or periodogram of the signal P[k] = (|X[k]|^2)/N
7. apply the filter bank to the periodogram or energy of the signal and log the sums
   S[m] = ln{H[k] * E[k]}
   S[m] = ln{H[k] * P[k]}
8. apply DCT
   c[n] = S[m] * cos(pi*n*(m+(1/2))/M)

Comparing the MFCC values obtained using this method with the values calculated using [matlab functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/cepstralcoefficients.html), I get approximately the same picture, but apparently matlab function has a different kind of normalization and the filter bank is calculated in a different way, my values are approximately an order of magnitude greater than the values obtained in matlab.

Also, my implementation gives more frames, i.e. a sound signal with 6400 samples has 26 = 6400/480-240 frames in my case and 25 in matlab.

The calculations before applying the filter bank are roughly similar, except that in my case the FFT is calculated with a length of 512 points, while the stft() function in matlab gives 241 values, i.e. a 480-point conversion. The **filter banks** also differ by about an order of magnitude in values, but if use a filter bank with values divided by 10, the picture is not similar of matlab's

**filter banks**
[image: filter banks]

Accordingly, the **mel-spectrum** (7 step) image shows that the first peak in my values (on the right) is not displayed, and the **MFCC**  image shows that the values of the coefficients differ by about an order of magnitude.

**mel-spectrum**
[image: mel-spectrum]

**MFCC**
[image: MFCC]

Which could be the reason for these values?

Thank you for your time